# Flutter file download issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder

My book download flutter application are downloaded file from api and read app itself but the issue is small size file are downloaded fully and read successfully but 250mb file are not downloading fully so can't read a book app throws error
Error below:

Exhausted heap space, trying to allocate 2147483664 bytes.
E/flutter ( 4858): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Out of Memory
E/flutter ( 4858): #0

I expact 250mb file download and read successful in my application only

Comment: You can use pagination in api calling to reduce server load in this case.

Comment: hard to say without the code, but if you're downloading the file into a variable - don't. Download it to a file, when using Dio you'd call `download` method https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Dio/download.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.